# Custom templates in pkgdown

Tags: r, pkgdown

[Here](https://github.com/r-lib/pkgdown/blob/b620ea1cc17b3b959165f8de7c7a063bfd09b2f0/R/render.r#L9), the [pkgdown](https://github.com/r-lib/pkgdown) docs say that I can supply my own templates (footer, etc) using the `templates_path` key in `_pkgdown.yml`. I am struggling to make [pkgdown](https://github.com/r-lib/pkgdown) notice my custom footer from https://github.com/wlandau-lilly/drake/commit/2ca610f932be8d504560027b70106b5d57e3f0ea, and I have not been able to find any guiding examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently, this feature was not officially implemented: https://github.com/r-lib/pkgdown/issues/486.

Comment: Thanks for following up on your question, landau. I was able to figure it out. My solution is below as a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with the [GitHub commit you linked](https://github.com/wlandau-lilly/drake/commit/2ca610f932be8d504560027b70106b5d57e3f0ea), change

```
templates_path: inst/pkgdown
```

to

```
template:
  path: "inst/pkgdown"
```

Leave your custom footer as `inst/pkgdown/footer.html`.